# Checking in C# a VB.NET object for null gives unexpected compile error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Checking in C# a VB.NET object for null gives unexpected compile error:

```cs
// Cannot compile:
var basePackage = BasePackage.GetFromID(id); // GetFromID is from VB.NET
if (basePackage != null) // Errormesage: "Cannot implicitly convert 'object' to 'bool'
{
}
```

Resharper's suggested fix:

```cs
// Can compile
if ((bool) (basePackage != null))
{
    linkedGroups = basePackage.GetLinkedGroups();
}
```

I have a colleague that have done this in a year without any problems. My colleague is using Visual Studio 2012 and I'm using Visual Studio 2013.
Could it be some kind of a settings?

Why is `basePackage != null` an `object`?

I know VB.NET has `Nothing` where C# has `null`.

**UPDATE:**
BasePackage's inherited this from another class:
I don't know if that's helps in any ways.

```vb
Public Shared Operator =([object] As CMSObject, type As System.Type)
    Return [object].GetType Is type
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>([object] As CMSObject, type As System.Type)
    Return [object].GetType IsNot type
End Operator

Public Shared Operator =([object] As CMSObject, o As Object)
    Return [object].GetType Is o
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>([object] As CMSObject, o As Object)
    Return [object].GetType IsNot o
End Operator
```

**SOLUTION:** 
When I outcomment these two operators C# is working fine again.

```vb
Public Shared Operator =([object] As CMSObject, type As System.Type)
    Return [object].GetType Is type
End Operator

'Public Shared Operator <>([object] As CMSObject, type As System.Type)
'    Return [object].GetType IsNot type
'End Operator

Public Shared Operator =([object] As CMSObject, o As Object)
    Return [object].GetType Is o
End Operator

'Public Shared Operator <>([object] As CMSObject, o As Object)
'    Return [object].GetType IsNot o
'End Operator
```

**Final Solution** Added type in VB.NET. No need for C# cast then.

```
Public Shared Operator =([object] As CMSObject, type As System.Type) **As Boolean**
    Return [object].GetType Is type
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>([object] As CMSObject, type As System.Type) **As Boolean**
    Return [object].GetType IsNot type
End Operator

Public Shared Operator =([object] As CMSObject, o As Object) **As Boolean**
    Return [object].GetType Is o
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>([object] As CMSObject, o As Object) **As Boolean**
    Return [object].GetType IsNot o
End Operator
```

Comment: What does the signature of `GetFromID` actually look like in VB?

Comment: Public Shared Function GetFromID(ByVal jobID As Integer) As BasePackage

Comment: What does the `BasePackage` look like? Does it contain any operators?

Comment: I'm don't know. BasePackage is over 5000 lines. What would be good search-words? I don't know what to look for.

Comment: @CodeCaster no hit on either "Operator" or "operator".

Comment: @CodeCaster I found some operators in it's superclass. See update.

Comment: You could try using `Object.ReferenceEquals(null, basePackage)`

Comment: Wow, those operators look like a really poorly thought out idea. Making equals and not-equals being type tests instead is... not good.

Comment: I can but it should't be necessary and I would like to know why. :)

Comment: Could it be that BasePackage returns a struct instead of object and that the compiler just can't figure it out?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you point me in the right direction. (@CodeCaster too), because after your comment I outcommented the 4 operators and now my C# works as expected. (I havn't wrote those operators or even knew they were there).

Comment: Breaking guidelines on overloading equality operators is never a good idea.

Comment: I have added the solutions. I wish I could give people points in comments! I am very gratefull.

Comment: Whilst you may have fixed your c# compiler error, be aware that if there was code actually relying on those functions (why else would they exist?), you may well have broken that and get unexpected runtime errors now...

Comment: Why do the operators return `Object`? (!) Set the [strict compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to `on` and specify a proper return type, `Boolean`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - I guess having strict off was easier when interacting with the CMS system. (I am not advocating this but I can see the advantage)

Comment: @JamesThorpe By solution I mean that's what gave the unexpected behavior, and I could proof it by outcomment it. My actually solution I wont outcomment the superclass but live with my cast. Now I at least now why I have to live with it. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I don't know why because I didn't wrote them and they have been there forever. What I can say though is that I think when using those operators in pure VB.NET code the VB.NET take care of that cast for you. So I think no one else ever thought about it before I (in C#) started to use that class. That would be a guess. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your vb sample, combpiled it into a dll and decompiled it to c#
That's how you operators look

```
public static object operator ==(Class1 @object, Type type)
{
  return (object) (bool) (@object.GetType() == type ? 1 : 0);
}

public static object operator !=(Class1 @object, Type type)
{
  return (object) (bool) (@object.GetType() != type ? 1 : 0);
}

public static object operator ==(Class1 @object, object o)
{
  return (object) (bool) (@object.GetType() == o ? 1 : 0);
}

public static object operator !=(Class1 @object, object o)
{
  return (object) (bool) (@object.GetType() != o ? 1 : 0);
}
```

So, it is just due to the strange operator overload signature.

You commented "Not Equal" operators, now it seems to work, but you will get the same error when you write something like

```
if ( (basePackage == null))
// etc.
```

The solution would be, as suggested in comments, to specify your operator overload signature as Boolean.